# Websphere 8.5.5.7 with Java7: existing profiles are not starting

Tags: java, websphere, java-7, websphere-8

I have a WebSphere for Developers version 8.5.5.4 working with Java7 on SLES11SP3 64bit. 
Java:
Package name: IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional) 7.0.4.1
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr4fp1ifix-20130423_02(SR4 FP1+IV38579+IV38399+IV40208))

I faced an issue which is solved by fixpack 8.5.5.6 (or 8.5.5.7).
Since I installed 8.5.5.7, all of the existing profiles fail to start. I made some digging, and found that Java has to be patched too. Related: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002#WebSphere%208.5.5%20Java%207

I installed Java7 SR9 then SR9FP10 interim fixes, but no luck:

- 7.0.1.0-WS-WASJavaSDK7-LinuxX64-IFPI42775
- 7.0.1.0-WS-WASJavaSDK7-LinuxX64-IFPI45305

Then I installed Java 7.1 optional package:
SDK Java(TM) Technology Edition Version 7.1.3.10 for WebSphere Application Server Version 8.5.5 Fix Pack 7.

I used the managesdk.sh command to change sdk on profiles. 
When I start the profile, only startServer.log contains informations.

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
Host Operating System is Linux, version 3.0.101-0.47.52-default
Java version = 1.7.0, Java Runtime Version = pxa6470_27sr3fp10-20150708_01 (SR3 FP10), Java Compiler = j9jit27, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
user.install.root = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/MEBIR2
Java Home = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/jre
ws.ext.dirs = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/MEBIR2/properties:
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM
/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/lib/tools.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar
Java Library path = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/native/linux/x86_64/:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/nulldllsdir:/usr/lib
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb727-20150520.00
Current trace specification = *=info
************* End Display Current Environment *************
[11/12/15 13:34:36:905 CET] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[11/12/15 13:34:37:020 CET] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the MEBIR2 profile
[11/12/15 13:34:37:025 CET] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: mebir
[11/12/15 13:34:37:041 CET] 00000001 ImplFactory   W   WSVR0072W: Ignoring undeclared override of interface, com.ibm.websphere.cluster.topography.DescriptionManager, with implementation,     com.ibm.ws.cluster.propagation.bulletinboard.BBDescriptionManager
[11/12/15 13:34:37:250 CET] 00000001 ModelMgr      I   WSVR0801I: Initializing all server configuration models
[11/12/15 13:34:40:280 CET] 00000001 WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled.
[11/12/15 13:34:40:568 CET] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
[11/12/15 13:34:41:774 CET] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. Server logs, startServer.log, and other log files under     /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/MEBIR2/logs/mebir should contain failure information.
```

But when I create a fresh new profile with pmt and change the sdk to 1.7.1_64, the server starts successfully. What could be the problem with the existing profiles?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What's reported on the files under ffdc folder?

Comment: Nothing comes to ffdc :(

Comment: What about native_stderr.log and native_stdout.log?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira
newest logs under... last time stderr.log was written when I had OutOfMemoryError, which would be solved by the fixpack

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was  306800 Nov 11 22:31 SystemOut_15.11.11_23.00.00.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was   27890 Nov 12 10:18 native_stdout.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was   20691 Nov 12 10:18 native_stderr.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was     974 Nov 12 10:19 SystemErr.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was   21086 Nov 12 10:21 stopServer.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was  277588 Nov 12 10:21 SystemOut.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 was was   52301 Nov 12 14:49 startServer.log

Comment: The only times I've experienced similar problems (profiles not starting) was due to illegal configuration/parameterization, most often illegal VM parameters. Was the profile changed prior to the last shutdown?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira
last time the server.xml file changed was on Oct 15

I checked the server.xml file's jvmEntries section between the old and the newly created profile.
The new had these missing: initialHeapSize="128" maximumHeapSize="512"
and executableJarFileName="" disableJIT="false" from debugArgs.
Cleared these settings from the old server.xml, but still the same.

Are there any more jvm related settings/files?

Comment: You could just check the files to see which ones (.xml) were recently changed.
Can you successfully export/restore (via manageprofiles.sh -backupProfile MEBIR2 -backupFile /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/MEBIR2/backup.zip and manageprofiles.sh -restoreProfile -backupFile /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/logs/manageprofiles/MEBIR2/backup.zip) the damaged profile?

Comment: Maybe you updated profile using `root` account, and running WebSphere using some `was` account? After applying fixpacks in that case you should do `chown` on the whole WebSphere/AppServer folder.

Comment: @Gas
You are totally right. I did a chown -R was on the profile that was running by was account, and everything works perfect. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you updated profile using `root` account, and running WebSphere using some `was` account? After applying fixpacks in that case you should do `chown -R` on the whole `WebSphere/AppServer` folder.